# Ways to protect my application from external API changes

Tags: c#, api

I'm wondering about some templates or patterns regarding how to protect my application from changes in external APIs, for example, inside of MS Azure or any other company's API. What is the best way to do it and minimize changes in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to essentially make your own API within your program. Partition the external API consumption with the use of interfaces, so if the external API changes, you can edit the implementation only, as the interface contracts will hold the rest of the program together.

Comment: Also this is usually pretty damn hard to get right. Good luck.

Comment: This is known as a Facade or Adapter pattern depending on how you implement it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern